# Cannot set a minimum TLS version for FrontDoor in terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, tls1.2, azure-front-door

I am using terraform 1.44. When I try to run this:

```
resource "azurerm_frontdoor" "frontdoor" {
  name                                         = "my-fd"
  location                                     = "${azurerm_resource_group.default.location}"
  resource_group_name                          = "${azurerm_resource_group.default.name}"
  enforce_backend_pools_certificate_name_check = false

  routing_rule {
    .....
  }

  backend_pool_load_balancing {
    ......
  }

  backend_pool_health_probe {
    .....
  }

  backend_pool {
    .......
  }

  frontend_endpoint {
    name                                    = "myFrontendEndpoint"
    host_name                               = "my-custom.hostname.com"
    custom_https_provisioning_enabled       = true
    custom_https_configuration {
      certificate_source = "FrontDoor"
      minimum_tls_version = "1.2"
    }
  }
}
```

It is failing with

> Error:
>   "frontend_endpoint.custom_https_configuration.minimum_tls_version":
>   this field cannot be set

According to [this](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/4434) GitHub issue it should be resolved already, but documentation link is broken... And in current documentation there is no mention of this field...

How can I create this frontend? Without setting the `minimum_tls_version` it errors with

> Error enabling Custom Domain HTTPS for Frontend Endpoint: frontdoor.FrontendEndpointsClient#EnableHTTPS: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="BadRequest" Message="\"minimumTlsVersion\" is a mandatory parameter."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Azure front door SSL configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-faq#ssl-configuration),

> All Front Door profiles created after September 2019 **use TLS 1.2 as
>   the default minimum.**
>
> Front Door supports TLS versions 1.0, 1.1 and 1.2. TLS 1.3 is not yet
>   supported.

From the [terraform document](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/frontdoor.html#minimum_tls_version), the attribute `minimum_tls_version` only could be exported from `custom_https_configuration` block. It can not be set like an Argument Reference.

For example,

```
....
      frontend_endpoint {
        name                              = "exampleFrontendEndpoint1"
        host_name                         = "example-FrontDoor.azurefd.net"

        custom_https_provisioning_enabled       = true
        custom_https_configuration {
          certificate_source = "FrontDoor"

      }
      }
    }

    output "minimum_tls_version" {
      value = "${azurerm_frontdoor.example.frontend_endpoint[0].custom_https_configuration[0].minimum_tls_version}"
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! When I first tried without `minimum_tls_version` I was using 1.42 and it failed. Then I tried to add this field and updating the azure provider at the same time. But on 1.44 you can skip it as you suggested. Nice!

Comment: Yes, I use 1.44